# what is the use of "wgetrc" command in wget download

Tags: linux, unix, ftp, wget, sftp

What is purpose of "wgetrc" in the below commands.

```
 -sh-3.00$ WGETRC=/hom1/spyga/spp/wgetrc_local wget  --directory-prefix=/home1/spyga/spp/download  ftp://127.0.0.1/outgoing/DATA.ZIP
```

wgetrc_local files having the credentials of ftp server.

normally i am downloading the files from ftp server using below command.

```
-sh-3.00$ wget --ftp-user=xyz--ftp-password=12345 ftp://localhost/outgoing/DATA.ZIP
```

what is the different between above commands.

Please help me out to understand the commands.
Thanks you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first command simply specifies an alternative configuration file to use instead of the default `~/.wgetrc`. You could also specify it using `--config=/hom1/spyga/spp/wgetrc_local` as argument to wget.

This file can contain [wgetrc commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Wgetrc-Commands.html#Wgetrc-Commands) that change the behaviour of wget. In this case it's probably done so user and passwords don't have to be supplied on the command line. Specially on multiuser systems it is a security risk to pass passwords on the command line, as that can possibly be viewd by other users, so it's a little better to store them in a file with restricted access permissions instead. This way only processes started by the owner of the file can access it.

Another use of the wget startup file is to change it's default settings, user agent etc...

It's all documented [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Startup-File.html#).